# Centre of mass in Relativistic System

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, rotational-kinematics

We define the center of mass to be the point where, if force is applied, the system shall have linear acceleration without angular acceleration. But, think about a system of two balls, uneven in mass connected through a massless rod/force transmitter. If I applied a force at the center of mass which is weighted mean of dist of balls, the force applied would move the large ball first as forces travel at finite speed(we must assume that in a relativistic setting right?). So, going by this logic, the centre of mass must be a little away form the massive ball than previously calculated.

Comment: I think your thought experiment is not realistic. The center of mass you determine in the lab by the force method already takes into account the transmission of forces difference  an infinitesimal  small value anyway, considering the speed of light. Any difference with a calculated cmwould be the same as zero as far as measuring goes.

Comment: @anna v, I was talking about the theoretical calculation of cm. We assume instantaneous transmission of forces when we calculate cm because while showing torque across such a point is zero, we calculate and negate the torque on both ends simultaneously

Comment: The definition you provide for a centre of mass is only valid in the case of a rigid body. As you correctly note, rigid bodies are not compatible with special relativity. It’s the definition, not the calculation, that needs updating.

Comment: Wouldn't the force move through the mass at it's speed of sound?

Comment: @AdrianHoward, I think the motion of atoms in force transmission will be perpendicular to the motion of particles in case of sound, basically, force shall travel as transverse waves rather than longitudinal ones. But this I say only in case of trying to rotat bodies with rods, if it was something compressive, the force shall probably travel at speed of sound.  Please let me know what you think.